# Guitar Tablature and Music sheet oriented plugins for wordpress or Drupal

Tags: php, python, wordpress, drupal

I'm familiar with wordpress and cakePHP; however, I'm building a small community website (hobby) that allows users to post music sheet (pdf/image) or guitar tabs ( text files). These music sheets should be organized by artists and songs. I've already built my own cms, but I'm not looking forward to maintain it as i'm scared I won't have the time.

An example of this would be [ultimate-guitar.com](http://ultimate-guitar.com) . Not the whole site, just the way they display tabs and stuff

[I posted a 1 month old build for you guys to see what i've done here](http://arabtabs.com/tab.php?id=15). the site for the most part works, but as i said, I'm scared that i won't be able to maintain it. This is not the latest build, i haven't gotten around to uploading it. It fixes most of the issues

Are there any music publishing plugins for drupal and wordpress (I haven't seen any personally)?
I'm open to other suggestions and comments as well so please feel free to mention them

Comment: This should probably be posted on a Drupal forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn’t sound like you have any music specific needs, you just need to be able to attach text, pdf or images to an item (node in Drupal) and assign tags to it.

You can use taxonomy in Drupal to assign artists to the nodes. I should think what you want is pretty simple to do. I would suggest that you try installing it and seeing what it can do.

Comment: a music sheet / tab is what users can post. each music sheet is assigned to a song, and each song is assignmed to one or multiple artists (some songs are covered by more than one artist). How can i set it up, so when a user clicks on an artist, it results in all the songs and tablatures, the same goes to songs?

Comment: Have a content type for music sheets and make sure your users can create it. Have two vocabularies (taxonomy) one for artist and one for song. Add these to the content type/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Guitar module](http://drupal.org/project/guitar), which will allow you to easily add chord fingerings to your tabs.